# C - Bubble Sort Program binary file

Tags: c, database, bubble-sort

I'm trying to make a Bubble Sort program in a binary file without using any arrays, instead of I will use fseek and fwrite functions.

Here is my code:

```
      typedef struct{  //Films
         short int year;
         char title[LEN_NAME];
         Genero_t gendre;
         float rateIMDB;
      }Ficha_t;

      FILE * fd;
      fd = fopen(name,"r+b");    
      Ficha_t aux1;
      Ficha_t aux2;
      int i,j,len;

        if (fd != NULL)
        {

        rewind(fd);
        fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        len=ftell(fd);
        rewind(fd);

        for(i=0;i<len;i++); 
        {
        for(j=0;j<len-1;j++)
        {

          fread(&aux1,sizeof(Ficha_t),1,fd);
          fread(&aux2,sizeof(Ficha_t),1,fd);

          if(strcmp(aux1.title,aux2.title)<0)
          {

            fseek(fd,-sizeof(Ficha_t)*2,SEEK_SET); //returning 2 positions for overwriting
            fwrite(&aux2, sizeof(Ficha_t), 1, fd);
            fwrite(&aux1, sizeof(Ficha_t), 1, fd);  
            fseek(fd,-sizeof(Ficha_t),SEEK_SET); //returning 1 position for checking again with the next film

          }
         }
        }
       }
```

It's not working since it's displaying the same 2 films, Where am I wrong? What could I do?

Comment: `len` isn't number of records. and Need rewind each inner loop.

Comment: Why should the program display anything at all? I can not find any `printf` call.

Comment: `fseek(fd,-sizeof(Ficha_t),SEEK_SET);` has to be done always at end of loop

Comment: @ceving It's used later and if it's not correctly ordered will return an error

Comment: @BLUEPIXY rewind to the beginning of file?

Comment: @Albermonte Yes, I think so.

Comment: SEEK_SET is the beginning of the file -- I don't think negative offsets make sense there.  SEEK_CUR is the current location

Comment: No one would do it this way in real life. a) merge sort is already better with files, b) mmap is faster anyway...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you want:

```
len=ftell(fd) / sizeof(Ficha_t);
```

to get the number of records in the file.

If you are trying to seek with offsets to the current location, use `SEEK_CUR`, not `SEEK_SET`.

I would add a bunch of printfs for `ftell(fd) / sizeof(Ficha_t)` so you can see that it's doing everything correctly. Also, you could be checking the return values of functions you are calling (they were probably returning errors as you tried to seek before the beginning and read/write there)

Answer (score 0):

Specific code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void fbubble_sort(const char *filename, size_t rec_size, bool (*needSwap)(const void *, const void *)){
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+b");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen, r+");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void *first  = malloc(rec_size);
    void *second = malloc(rec_size);
    if(!first || !second){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    enum { NO_SWAP = -1};

    long last_swap_pos;
    do {
        rewind(fp);
        long pos_1 = 0;//first record position
        last_swap_pos = NO_SWAP;
        if(0==fread(first, rec_size, 1, fp))
            break;
        while((pos_1 <= last_swap_pos || last_swap_pos == NO_SWAP) && 1==fread(second, rec_size, 1, fp) ){
            if(needSwap(first, second)){
                fseek(fp, pos_1, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(second, rec_size, 1, fp);
                fwrite(first,  rec_size, 1, fp);
                fflush(fp);
                last_swap_pos = pos_1;
            } else {
                //exchange buffer
                void *temp = first;
                first = second;
                second = temp;
            }
            pos_1 += rec_size;
        }
    }while(last_swap_pos != NO_SWAP);

    free(first);free(second);
    fclose(fp);
}

#define DATA_FILE "test.dat"
#define GREATERi(type, member)\
bool greater_i(const void *first, const void *second){\
    return ((type*)first)->member > ((type*)second)->member;\
}\
/**/
#define GREATERs(type, member)\
bool greater_s(const void *first, const void *second){\
    return strcmp((type*)first)->member, ((type*)second)->member) > 0;\
}\
/**/
#define LESSi(type, member)\
bool less(const void *first, const void *second){\
    return ((type*)first)->member < ((type*)second)->member;\
}\
/**/

typedef struct {
    unsigned v;
} Record;

GREATERi(Record, v)

int main(void){
    void make_test_data(void);
    void print_test_data(void);

    make_test_data();
    print_test_data();

    fbubble_sort(DATA_FILE, sizeof(Record), greater_i);

    print_test_data();
}

void make_test_data(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen(DATA_FILE, "wb");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen, w");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Record rec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        rec.v = rand() % 100;
        fwrite(&rec, sizeof(rec), 1, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void print_test_data(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen(DATA_FILE, "rb");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen, r");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Record rec;
    int cnt = 0;
    while(fread(&rec, sizeof(rec), 1, fp)){
        if(cnt)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%2u", rec.v);
        if(++cnt == 10){
            putchar('\n');
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    fclose(fp);
}
```